# Forms aвторизация через модифицированный WebClient с куками

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-apps, cookie, auth

Доброго дня. Есть сайт первый и второй. 
Нужно получить доступ к защищенному методу в первом, используя стандартный механизм авторизации форм.
WebClient  на втором сайте делает запрос на авторизацию, отсылая имя/пароль, ему приходит кука, он ее сохраняет и посылает второй запрос на защищенный метод с кукой.
Во втором запросе видна AUTH кука и она валидна, но авторизация не проходит.

```
Request.isauthenticated = false
```

В чем может быть дело?

Код запросов вебклиента

```
    //Create an instance of your new CookieAware Web Client
var client = new CookieAwareWebClient();

//Authenticate (username and password can be either hard-coded or pulled from a settings area)
var values = new NameValueCollection { { "Name", "name" }, { "Password", "1234" } };

//Perform authentication - after this has been performed the cookie will be stored within the Web Client
client.UploadValues(new Uri("http://localhost:15536/Plugins/ProductListGetter/login"), "POST", values);
var _cookies = client.ResponseHeaders["Set-Cookie"];

client.UploadString(new Uri("http://localhost:15536/Plugins/ProductListGetter/ChangeNameForCurrentUser"), "POST", "Example Message");
client.UploadString(new Uri("http://localhost:15536/Plugins/ProductListGetter/ChangeNameForCurrentUser"), "POST", "Example Message");
client.Dispose();
```

Код модифицированного вебклиента для поддержки кук

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    //Properties to handle implementing a timeout
    private int? _timeout = null;
    public int? Timeout
    {
        get
        {
            return _timeout;
        }
        set
        {
            _timeout = value;
        }
    }

    //A CookieContainer class to house the Cookie once it is contained within one of the Requests
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; private set; }

    //Constructor
    public CookieAwareWebClient()
    {
        CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    }

    //Method to handle setting the optional timeout (in milliseconds)
    public void SetTimeout(int timeout)
    {
        _timeout = timeout;
    }

    //This handles using and storing the Cookie information as well as managing the Request timeout
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        //Handles the CookieContainer
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
        //Sets the Timeout if it exists
        if (_timeout.HasValue)
        {
            request.Timeout = _timeout.Value;
        }
        return request;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено.
Нужно было  добавить cookieless="UseCookies" в конфиг.